What tier are Pathfinder Classes from Legendary Games?
What I'm asking is basically an extension of this answered question:
What tier are the Pathfinder classes?
I'm interested in how reworked classes from Legendary ... series by Legendary games fare against originals. I heard a lot about how those reworked classes supposedly fix/improve them and I'd love to know if it's indeed a fact that can be put into Tier System.

It’s a good question, but note that the less-played some content is, the less sure tiers are going to be. I don’t know how relatively popular the Legendary series is, but as 3rd-party content it’s going to be a minuscule fraction of D&D 3.5e/PF 1e. And D&D 3.5e is 20 years old and Pathfinder 1e’s content is largely the same stuff. So to the extent these do new and different things (I’m entirely unfamiliar with the work), there’s going to be (or should be, if we’re being honest) greater uncertainty when tiering them.

I don't expect high accuracy here, well aware of the statistical player numbers. But if some classes are positioned wildly different from 1pp that at least serves as guidance, if not binary information.

Valid, just thought the point should be made. Unfortunately, I can’t really help you, but hopefully someone can.

It may be worth noting that 'fixes and improvements' may not affect Tier scaling at all; there are ways to make classes more fun, interesting, and/or functional that would not make them improve on the Tier system. Not to say this question isn't valid; just saying that there may or may not be any change for various classes.

I also fully expect this. Thing is, they literally reworked 95% of classes in the game, so I expect at least a couple major Tier changes. At the very least to the classes that occupied bottom Tiers. Here's hoping someone did play with those and will be able to answer.
